# jQuery: Pop a dialog box on selecting a table

Tags: jquery, select, dialog, popup

I need to open a dialog box when a table is selected on a webpage. I am able to open the dialog box using the id element of the table and mouseup function. But this won't work for tables that don't have the "id" field set. I came across the [select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) and I can see it works for input elements but I can't get it to work for table elements

Here is my current working code

```js
function getSelected() {
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    } else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
        if (selection.text) {
            return selection.text;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

$('#test').mouseup(function () {
    var selection = getSelected();

    if (selection) {
        var arr = [];
        var vals = $('#test').find('td').filter(function () {
            //get only <td> that contain numeric value inside it
            return $.isNumeric(this.innerHTML);
        }).each(function (i, val) {
            arr.push(val.innerHTML);
        });
        alert(arr);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

This works only for tables having an id field set to "test"

And here is what I tried using select
It works for input but not table.

```js
$( ":input" ).select(function() {
  $( "div" ).text( "table was selected" ).show();
});
$( ":table" ).select(function() {
  $( "div" ).text( "text was selected" ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <p>Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.</p>
 <table id="test" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>     
  <div></div>
      </body>
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. New to jQuery. Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) to select all the tables in the page. The [:input selctor](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is a special selector which will select all input fields like `input`, `select`, `textarea` and `button`

```
$( "table" ).select(function() {
  $( "div" ).text( "text was selected" ).show();
});
```

There is no such selector as `:table`

Comment: @ayushi you need to select a part of the text... or change the event to click event

Comment: basically what i was trying to do was on selecting the table, a pop up with numerical data was being displayed. but its not working using this. here is the js fiddle using your suggesting. http://jsfiddle.net/PQbb7/101/

Answer (score 1):

You may use the "table" selector to select all tables on the page. Then apply a handler to each table. In this case clicking on the table may be used so use the click event. Like this:

```js
$( "table" ).on('click', function() {
  $( "div" ).text( "text was selected" ).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <input type="text" value="Some text">
  <p>Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.</p>
 <table id="test" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Jill</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Eve</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>94</td>
    </tr>
</table>     
  <div></div>
      </body>
```